# "Re-parenting" GIT feature branch based on another

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

I am hoping someone knows the git-fu required to untangle a branch mess.

I have a feature branch - FB2 - whose parent is FB1, which in turn originated from master.

Bad news: I need to retarget FB2 on top of master as it needs to ship before FB1, without any of the commits from FB1.

Good news: There are few code changes in FB2 that directly interact with changesets from FB1. However, there are dozens and dozens of commits from pull requests over many tickets (~75) from both FB1 and FB2.

I'm looking for the least painful way to find and incorporate only the commits which were committed directly to FB2. Alternatively, a way to alter the existing FB2 branch to retarget master and remove all the commits that originated from FB1.

brute force cherry picking or rebasing will take forever and be error prone.

*"git rebase --onto master FB1"* didn't seem to work in a test. The changes from FB1 were still present in FB2.

Thanks!

Similar to the diagram here:

```
# CURRENT
A--B--C--D // master
          \
           E--F--G // FB1
                  \
                   H--I--J // FB2
# DESIRED

          H--I--J // FB2
         /       \
A--B--C--D        M // merged
          \
           E--F--G // FB1
```

Comment: What `git rebase --onto master FB1` does depends on what branch you're currently on. It's equivalent to `git rebase --onto master FB1 <current branch>`. If you were on `FB2` it should have been what you are asking for, however it's unclear to me what you intend `M` to be.

Comment: M should be all the changesets from the pull requests which were developed for and merged into FB2, on top of the existing code from master.

Comment: I tested the "rebase --onto" syntax using test branches I created to represent the scenario to see what would happen.  

Basically, A < B < C, with A regularly merged into B and B regularly merged into C.  When I ran it -- attempting to retarget C onto A -- C still seemed to have commits associated with B.

Comment: In your comment you are talking about merges but in your example in the question there are no merges involved. I'm also not sure if the A, B, C from your comment are the same A, B, C as in the question or if they correspond to master, FB1, FB2.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to keep it simple. Master (in reality, master is actually a versioned release branch) is regularly merged into FB1 and FB1 is regularly merged into FB2.

FB1 was just finishing active development when FB2 started. But there have been bug fixes and other items checked in to FB1 which were then merged to FB2. So it's definitely not as clean as the over-simplified diagram. 

Looking at the commits "in" FB2, some are from FB1 items (pulled in from the FB1->FB2 merges) and some are from FB2 pull requests, interspersed over time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any re-merges between FB1 and FB2 ? Or you just branched of fb1 and fb2 then had its own history? if so :

you may try creating the patch between commits G and J:

```
git diff #G..#J > mypatch.patch
```

then create a new branch where you actually want to start from and apply the patch:

```
git apply mypatch.patch
```

However, if files do not exist on the new target branch, the patch fill not apply cleanly.

for that you may first want to do :

```
 git diff --name-status #G..#J
```

to identify what actual files changed.

Comment: Yeah, so master (in this case, it's really a release branch but I was trying to keep things simple) is regularly merged into FB1 and FB1 merged into FB2.  So it's definitely not as clean as the over-simplified diagram. Looking at the commit history of FB2, some are from FB1 items (from the FB1->FB2 merges) and some are from FB2 pull requests, interspersed.

Comment: as you may know git branch is just a pointer to the last commit. If you have interleaving branches, you will not figure out which commits in the history belong to witch branch.